# Webform with existing contact results in undefine index

Tags: webform-civicrm

Running into this problem in a form to create an activity with two existing contacts.  The form creates the activity successfully, but the UX is marred by angry red error messages.  I replicated the problem in a test form with nothing but one existing contact.  This test form is accessible at http://cc.unidosnow.org/node/7?cid1=200.    Submitting the test form results in similar error messages as seen with the full fledged form:

- Notice: Undefined index: address in wf_crm_webform_postprocess->saveContactLocation() (line 751 of /home/unidosnow/www/www/sites/all/modules/webform_civicrm/includes/wf_crm_webform_postprocess.inc).
- Notice: Undefined index: email in wf_crm_webform_postprocess->saveContactLocation() (line 752 of /home/unidosnow/www/www/sites/all/modules/webform_civicrm/includes/wf_crm_webform_postprocess.inc).

Seems to be wanting address and email (to enable contact creation?), but the only thing checked in the webform's CiviCRM tab is Existing Contact and that's all I need from the contacts in the full fledged form.

I am running CiviCRM 7.x-4.7.29, Drupal 7.58, Webform 7.x-4.16, Webform CiviCRM Integration 7.x-4.20, PHP 5.6.

Thoughts?

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem! I am using the webform to create a new case using an existing contact. All the values are stored correctly when submitted but I don't want to show the user the ugly message!

Comment: Ben's case - https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm/issues/2966760

Comment: Same message here on creation of new activity.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar error with a form which is just a mailing group subscription form with a couple of additional custom fields - as a workaround I included an address field and changed that field to hidden - the php notice isn't triggered, and the form doesn't try to fill in the address.

Comment: I also resorted to that workaround.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a fix for this issue has been committed to the webform_civicrm project and should be present in version 7.x-4.21+

Details are here: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm/issues/2966760

The fix itself is here: https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/139