# webform-civicrm error when creating CiviCRM custom data group

Tags: webform-civicrm

When creating (or saving) a custom data group or (field)set the following error pops up:

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in webform_civicrm_civicrm_postSave_civicrm_custom_group() (line 436 of /home/unidosnow/www/www/sites/all/modules/webform_civicrm/webform_civicrm.module)

The code throwing this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_civicrm_postSave_tableName().
 *
 * Handles adding/editing a custom group.
 *
 * @param CRM_Core_DAO_CustomGroup $dao
 */
function webform_civicrm_civicrm_postSave_civicrm_custom_group($dao) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.components');

  // get all fieldsets with custom group ID
  $customGroupId = $dao->id;
  $dbResource = db_query("SELECT * FROM {webform_component} WHERE type ='fieldset' "
          . "AND form_key LIKE '%cg{$customGroupId}_fieldset'");
  $fieldsets = $dbResource->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  // check if dao fields have been fetched
  if (!$dao->title) {
    $dao->find(TRUE);
  }

  // run only if the title of the custom group has changed in civicrm
  -->>  if ($fieldsets[0]['name'] != $dao->title) {  <<-- Exception here
    foreach ($fieldsets as $field_info) {
      $component = array();
      $component['name'] = $dao->title;
      $component['type'] = $field_info['type'];
      $component['form_key'] = $field_info['form_key'];
      $component['weight'] = $field_info['weight'];
      $component['nid'] = $field_info['nid'];
      $component['cid'] = $field_info['cid'];
      $component['pid'] = $field_info['pid'];
      webform_component_update($component);
    }
  }
}
```

The custom set creates successfully, haven't yet tried to use it in a webform.  Before the 4/25 update I had created custom data sets without this error.  Don't have record of the versions I was using at the time, the current versions that show the problem are CiviCRM 4.7.29, Drupal Core 7.59, webform-civicrm 4.20, and webform 4.17.

Comment: Is the webform functional working? Does it update/insert the data you want? If so I would say it is a notice and ignore it. If it doesn't work the notice might be a clue in finding the cause but not neccesarly be the cause.

Comment: Finally had a chance to test.  Despite the Notices, the custom CiviCRM fields are exposed and processed correctly by Webform.  I'll ignore the Notices.

Answer (score 2):

This was not a bug that caused any loss of functionality, just a php notice which has since been fixed via this patch: https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/139

Comment: would you mind double-checking?  DRU-2966760 was about a [different PHP notice](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24626/webform-with-existing-contact-results-in-undefine-index?noredirect=1#comment27939_24626).  And thanks for patching that!

Comment: I think the pr got linked to the wrong issue but if you look at the code you'll see it fixed the line you pointed to in your question.